# Specific docking to the frame

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, docking, dockpanel

Now my bars located on frame thanks to nDockBarID = AFX_IDW_DOCKBAR_LEFT

```
    ForcesBar* m_forcesBar[3];

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    m_forcesBar[i]->SetBarStyle(m_forcesBar[i]->GetBarStyle() | 
        CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC);
    m_forcesBar[i]->EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
}

pMainFrame->EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);

pMainFrame->DockControlBar(m_forcesBar[0], AFX_IDW_DOCKBAR_LEFT); 
pMainFrame->DockControlBar(m_forcesBar[1], AFX_IDW_DOCKBAR_LEFT); 
pMainFrame->DockControlBar(m_forcesBar[2], AFX_IDW_DOCKBAR_LEFT);
```

[image]

While I want to receive such bar combination:

[image]

I think that it will be good to use lpRect in

```
void DockControlBar(
   CControlBar* pBar,
   UINT nDockBarID = 0,
   LPCRECT lpRect = NULL 
);
```

but unfortunately it does not work.
Can you give code example for making such specific doking (secon picture).

(In project I use CSizingControlBar http://www.datamekanix.com/sizecbar/manual.html)

Comment: How about using `AFX_IDW_DOCKBAR_BOTTOM` instead of `AFX_IDW_DOCKBAR_LEFT`?

Comment: If so, I will receive bars in left and bottom of the screen. There is nothing common with picture 2 in this way.

Comment: Attila, here is the picture of your solution: http://me4u.ru/i/ywy.jpg

Comment: With all 3 of the `LEFT`s replaced with `BOTTOM`s?  I would have expected the frames under each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it and using rectangle works fine.
One difference is that in my test app I have declared m_forcesBar in MainFrm.h as

```
ForcesBar m_forcesBar[3];
```

Avoiding allocation on the heap and remembering memory release.

The code I used (snippet from OnCreate):

```
    EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);

m_wndToolBar1.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
m_wndToolBar2.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);

DockControlBar(&m_wndToolBar1);
DockControlBar(&m_wndToolBar2);

CRect rectWnd;
GetClientRect(rectWnd);
ClientToScreen(rectWnd);

for(int iIndx = 0; iIndx < 3; iIndx++)
{
    if (!m_forcesBar[iIndx].Create(_T(""), this, 120 + iIndx))
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to create mybar\n");
        return -1;      // fail to create
    }

    m_forcesBar[iIndx].SetBarStyle(m_forcesBar[iIndx].GetBarStyle() |
        CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC);


    m_forcesBar[iIndx].EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_LEFT);



    DockControlBar(&m_forcesBar[iIndx], AFX_IDW_DOCKBAR_LEFT, rectWnd);


}
```

That is it.

Comment: Thanks. JohnCz, how can I set height of this bars while docking ?